# How disable other options after if specific option Is selected

Tags: angular

I have to implement the functionality to disable options from `mat-select` whenever the user selects one specific option from drop down, suppose options are

- A
- B
- C
- D

If D selected A,B,C should be disabled or if C selected A,B,D should be disabled. How can I do this ?

Thanks in advance.

I'm using Angular 9. I cannot put code here since its office work.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Even if it is "office work" you can create a minimal reproducible example. You can disable a `mat-option` via the `disabled` property - [link](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/d7e21091ad8a891029f7df0fb3412f4031745fd6/src/material/core/option/option.ts#L68)

Comment: This depends on a fair number of things (template vs reactive forms, dynamic vs static options, how those options are received...). We all understand that you can't copy/paste pro work here, but please provide a minimal reproduction.